# Reset Password through Graph API doesn't change the Password at all

Tags: azure-active-directory, passwords, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

The code below doesn't change the Password at all

**UPDATE** (Added instantiation of graphClient object):

```
string clientId = Configuration["AzureAd:ClientId"];
string tenantId = Configuration["AzureAd:TenantId"];
string authority = Configuration["AzureAd:Authority"]; 

string[] scopes = new string[] { "User.Read", "Directory.AccessAsUser.All", "User.Invite.All" };

IPublicClientApplication app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId)
    .WithAuthority(authority)
    .WithTenantId(tenantId)
    .Build();

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in user.Password.ToCharArray())  // you should fetch the password
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);  // keystroke by keystroke

var tokens = app.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, user.UserName, securePassword).ExecuteAsync().Result;

graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(x =>
    {
        x.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
            "Bearer", tokens.AccessToken);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
```

...

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword([FromBody] JObject data)
{
    try
    {
        await graphClient.Me
        .ChangePassword(data["currentPassword"].ToString(), data["newPassword"].ToString())
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();
...
}
```

When debugging, the code runs smoothly without any error or issue.
Normally I should login with the New Password. Sadly the Old Password is the only way to login. Is there something additionally required or another scope  I need to address (other than "Directory.AccessAsUser.All") ?

Comment: Please provide the code of how you implement `graphClient` and are you sure the `data` is OK?

Comment: @AllenWu were you aware of SaiSakethGuduru's answer?

Comment: Haven't gone through that answer but based on my test, I actually cannot use `/me/changePassword` to reset the password out of Microsoft Graph Explorer ( Yes, it's interesting that it works in Microsoft Graph explorer). I'm doing research to see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know we cannot change password Using Graph API

- **Unsupported end-user operations**

  - Any end user resetting their own password by using PowerShell version 1, version 2, or the **Microsoft Graph API.**

for further information read here
[On-premises password writeback with self-service password reset - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-writeback#unsupported-writeback-operations)

Comment: I enabled Self-Service Password Reset in Azure AD and thought this will solve the issue. Thank you for informing us.